# Relativistic Collision Mass Assumption

Tags: special-relativity

David Tong's Dynamics and Relativity Problem Set 4 Problem 7:

> A photon collides with a stationary electron of rest mass $m$. Show that the angle $\theta$ by which the photon is deflected is related to the magnitudes $p$ and $q$ of the photon's initial and final momenta by $$2\sin^2\theta = \frac{mc}{q} - \frac{mc}{p}$$

I got the desired answer by assuming that the electron has rest mass $m$ before and after the collision. I could not solve the problem without that assumption. But in relativistic collisions, mass often isn't conserved. How do we know when to make the assumption of conserved mass?

Comment: In particle physics "mass" mean the invariant mass (the thing called "rest mass" in the older nomenclature) and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still an electron, so it still has the electron's mass. When the mass changes in a relativistic collsion, it is because the particle type changes.